# Improved Perlin Noise 3D, strange behavior 0.5000 appears in whole sections

Tags: c++, perlin-noise

I translated the improved 3D perlin noise from [this](https://adrianb.io/2014/08/09/perlinnoise.html) webside from c# to c++.
But the resulting values are strange.

**First lets look at the code:**

```
#include "PerlinNoise.h"


PerlinNoise::PerlinNoise(int repeat) 
{
    this->repeat = repeat;

    for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
    {
        permutation[i] = i;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
    {
        int swapIndex = rand() % 256;
        std::swap(permutation[i], permutation[swapIndex]);
    }

    for (int x = 0; x<512; x++) {
        p[x] = permutation[x % 256];
    }
}

int PerlinNoise::inc(int num) 
{
    num++;
    if (repeat > 0) num %= repeat;

    return num;
}

float PerlinNoise::noise(float x, float y, float z) 
{
    if (repeat > 0) {                                   // If we have any repeat on, change the coordinates to their "local" repetitions
        x = fmodf(x, repeat);
        y = fmodf(y, repeat);
        z = fmodf(z, repeat);
    }

    int xi = (int)x & 255;                              // Calculate the "unit cube" that the point asked will be located in
    int yi = (int)y & 255;                              // The left bound is ( |_x_|,|_y_|,|_z_| ) and the right bound is that
    int zi = (int)z & 255;                              // plus 1.  Next we calculate the location (from 0.0 to 1.0) in that cube.
    float xf = x - static_cast<int>(x);                             // We also fade the location to smooth the result.
    float yf = y - static_cast<int>(y);
    float zf = z - static_cast<int>(z);
    float u = fade(xf);
    float v = fade(yf);
    float w = fade(zf);

    int aaa, aba, aab, abb, baa, bba, bab, bbb;
    aaa = p[p[p[xi] + yi] + zi];
    aba = p[p[p[xi] + inc(yi)] + zi];
    aab = p[p[p[xi] + yi] + inc(zi)];
    abb = p[p[p[xi] + inc(yi)] + inc(zi)];
    baa = p[p[p[inc(xi)] + yi] + zi];
    bba = p[p[p[inc(xi)] + inc(yi)] + zi];
    bab = p[p[p[inc(xi)] + yi] + inc(zi)];
    bbb = p[p[p[inc(xi)] + inc(yi)] + inc(zi)];

    float x1, x2, y1, y2;
    x1 = lerp(grad(aaa, xf, yf, zf),                // The gradient function calculates the dot product between a pseudorandom
        grad(baa, xf - 1, yf, zf),              // gradient vector and the vector from the input coordinate to the 8
        u);                                     // surrounding points in its unit cube.
    x2 = lerp(grad(aba, xf, yf - 1, zf),                // This is all then lerped together as a sort of weighted average based on the faded (u,v,w)
        grad(bba, xf - 1, yf - 1, zf),              // values we made earlier.
        u);
    y1 = lerp(x1, x2, v);

    x1 = lerp(grad(aab, xf, yf, zf - 1),
        grad(bab, xf - 1, yf, zf - 1),
        u);
    x2 = lerp(grad(abb, xf, yf - 1, zf - 1),
        grad(bbb, xf - 1, yf - 1, zf - 1),
        u);
    y2 = lerp(x1, x2, v);

    return (lerp(y1, y2, w) + 1) / 2;                       // For convenience we bound it to 0 - 1 (theoretical min/max before is -1 - 1)
}

float PerlinNoise::grad(int hash, float x, float y, float z) 
{
    int h = hash & 15;                                  // Take the hashed value and take the first 4 bits of it (15 == 0b1111)
    float u = h < 8 /* 0b1000 */ ? x : y;               // If the most significant bit (MSB) of the hash is 0 then set u = x.  Otherwise y.

    float v;                                            // In Ken Perlin's original implementation this was another conditional operator (?:).  I
                                                        // expanded it for readability.

    if (h < 4 /* 0b0100 */)                             // If the first and second significant bits are 0 set v = y
        v = y;
    else if (h == 12 /* 0b1100 */ || h == 14 /* 0b1110*/)// If the first and second significant bits are 1 set v = x
        v = x;
    else                                                // If the first and second significant bits are not equal (0/1, 1/0) set v = z
        v = z;

    return ((h & 1) == 0 ? u : -u) + ((h & 2) == 0 ? v : -v); // Use the last 2 bits to decide if u and v are positive or negative.  Then return their addition.
}

float PerlinNoise::fade(float t)
{
    // Fade function as defined by Ken Perlin.  This eases coordinate values
    // so that they will "ease" towards integral values.  This ends up smoothing
    // the final output.
    return t * t * t * (t * (t * 6 - 15) + 10);         // 6t^5 - 15t^4 + 10t^3
}

float PerlinNoise::lerp(float a, float b, float x) 
{
    return a + x * (b - a);
}

void main()
{
    PerlinNoise perlinNoise(-1);
    std::vector<float> results;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
    {
        results.push_back(perlinNoise.noise(static_cast<float>(i) * 0.1f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    }
}
```

**And of cause the output:**

```
x = 0.1 value = 0.45428         x = 0.2 value = 0.42896         x = 0.3 value = 0.43154         x = 0.4 value = 0.45872
x = 0.5 value = 0.5             x = 0.6 value = 0.54128         x = 0.7 value = 0.56846         x = 0.8 value = 0.57104
x = 0.9 value = 0.54572         x = 1 value = 0.5               x = 1.1 value = 0.450428        x = 1.2 value = 0.405792
x = 1.3 value = 0.374462        x = 1.4 value = 0.363488        x = 1.5 value = 0.375           x = 1.6 value = 0.404768
x = 1.7 value = 0.442922        x = 1.8 value = 0.476832        x = 1.9 value = 0.496148        x = 2 value = 0.5
x = 2.1 value = 0.5             x = 2.2 value = 0.5             x = 2.3 value = 0.5             x = 2.4 value = 0.5
x = 2.5 value = 0.5             x = 2.6 value = 0.5             x = 2.7 value = 0.5             x = 2.8 value = 0.5
x = 2.9 value = 0.5             x = 3 value = 0.5               x = 3.1 value = 0.5             x = 3.2 value = 0.5
x = 3.3 value = 0.5             x = 3.4 value = 0.5             x = 3.5 value = 0.5             x = 3.6 value = 0.5
x = 3.7 value = 0.5             x = 3.8 value = 0.5             x = 3.9 value = 0.5             x = 4 value = 0.5
x = 4.1 value = 0.496148        x = 4.2 value = 0.476832        x = 4.3 value = 0.442922        x = 4.4 value = 0.404768
x = 4.5 value = 0.375           x = 4.6 value = 0.363488        x = 4.7 value = 0.374462        x = 4.8 value = 0.405792
x = 4.9 value = 0.450428        x = 5 value = 0.5               x = 5.1 value = 0.553424        x = 5.2 value = 0.617376
x = 5.3 value = 0.682616        x = 5.4 value = 0.731744        x = 5.5 value = 0.75            x = 5.6 value = 0.731744
x = 5.7 value = 0.682616        x = 5.8 value = 0.617376        x = 5.9 value = 0.553424        x = 6 value = 0.5
x = 6.1 value = 0.450428        x = 6.2 value = 0.405792        x = 6.3 value = 0.374462        x = 6.4 value = 0.363488
x = 6.5 value = 0.375           x = 6.6 value = 0.404768        x = 6.7 value = 0.442922        x = 6.8 value = 0.476832
x = 6.9 value = 0.496148        x = 7 value = 0.5               x = 7.1 value = 0.503852        x = 7.2 value = 0.523168
x = 7.3 value = 0.557078        x = 7.4 value = 0.595232        x = 7.5 value = 0.625           x = 7.6 value = 0.636512
x = 7.7 value = 0.625538        x = 7.8 value = 0.594208        x = 7.9 value = 0.549572        x = 8 value = 0.5
x = 8.1 value = 0.446576        x = 8.2 value = 0.382624        x = 8.3 value = 0.317384        x = 8.4 value = 0.268256
x = 8.5 value = 0.25            x = 8.6 value = 0.268256        x = 8.7 value = 0.317384        x = 8.8 value = 0.382624
x = 8.9 value = 0.446576        x = 9 value = 0.5               x = 9.1 value = 0.553424        x = 9.2 value = 0.617376
x = 9.3 value = 0.682616        x = 9.4 value = 0.731744        x = 9.5 value = 0.75            x = 9.6 value = 0.731744
x = 9.7 value = 0.682616        x = 9.8 value = 0.617376        x = 9.9 value = 0.553424        x = 10 value = 0.5
x = 10.1 value = 0.450428       x = 10.2 value = 0.405792       x = 10.3 value = 0.374462       x = 10.4 value = 0.363488
x = 10.5 value = 0.375          x = 10.6 value = 0.404768       x = 10.7 value = 0.442922       x = 10.8 value = 0.476832
x = 10.9 value = 0.496148       x = 11 value = 0.5              x = 11.1 value = 0.496148       x = 11.2 value = 0.476832
x = 11.3 value = 0.442922       x = 11.4 value = 0.404768       x = 11.5 value = 0.375          x = 11.6 value = 0.363488
x = 11.7 value = 0.374462       x = 11.8 value = 0.405792       x = 11.9 value = 0.450428       x = 12 value = 0.5
x = 12.1 value = 0.549572       x = 12.2 value = 0.594208       x = 12.3 value = 0.625538       x = 12.4 value = 0.636512
x = 12.5 value = 0.625          x = 12.6 value = 0.595232       x = 12.7 value = 0.557078       x = 12.8 value = 0.523168
x = 12.9 value = 0.503852       x = 13 value = 0.5              x = 13.1 value = 0.496148       x = 13.2 value = 0.476832
x = 13.3 value = 0.442922       x = 13.4 value = 0.404768       x = 13.5 value = 0.375          x = 13.6 value = 0.363488
x = 13.7 value = 0.374462       x = 13.8 value = 0.405792       x = 13.9 value = 0.450428       x = 14 value = 0.5
x = 14.1 value = 0.54572        x = 14.2 value = 0.57104        x = 14.3 value = 0.56846        x = 14.4 value = 0.54128
x = 14.5 value = 0.5            x = 14.6 value = 0.45872        x = 14.7 value = 0.43154        x = 14.8 value = 0.42896
x = 14.9 value = 0.45428        x = 15 value = 0.5              x = 15.1 value = 0.54572        x = 15.2 value = 0.57104
x = 15.3 value = 0.56846        x = 15.4 value = 0.54128        x = 15.5 value = 0.5            x = 15.6 value = 0.45872
x = 15.7 value = 0.43154        x = 15.8 value = 0.42896        x = 15.9 value = 0.45428        x = 16 value = 0.5
x = 16.1 value = 0.549572       x = 16.2 value = 0.594208       x = 16.3 value = 0.625538       x = 16.4 value = 0.636512
x = 16.5 value = 0.625          x = 16.6 value = 0.595232       x = 16.7 value = 0.557078       x = 16.8 value = 0.523168
x = 16.9 value = 0.503852       x = 17 value = 0.5              x = 17.1 value = 0.496148       x = 17.2 value = 0.476832
x = 17.3 value = 0.442922       x = 17.4 value = 0.404768       x = 17.5 value = 0.375          x = 17.6 value = 0.363488
x = 17.7 value = 0.374462       x = 17.8 value = 0.405792       x = 17.9 value = 0.450428       x = 18 value = 0.5
x = 18.1 value = 0.549572       x = 18.2 value = 0.594208       x = 18.3 value = 0.625538       x = 18.4 value = 0.636512
x = 18.5 value = 0.625          x = 18.6 value = 0.595232       x = 18.7 value = 0.557078       x = 18.8 value = 0.523168
x = 18.9 value = 0.503852       x = 19 value = 0.5              x = 19.1 value = 0.503852       x = 19.2 value = 0.523168
x = 19.3 value = 0.557078       x = 19.4 value = 0.595232       x = 19.5 value = 0.625          x = 19.6 value = 0.636512
x = 19.7 value = 0.625538       x = 19.8 value = 0.594208       x = 19.9 value = 0.549572       x = 20 value = 0.5
x = 20.1 value = 0.45428        x = 20.2 value = 0.42896        x = 20.3 value = 0.43154        x = 20.4 value = 0.45872
x = 20.5 value = 0.5            x = 20.6 value = 0.54128        x = 20.7 value = 0.56846        x = 20.8 value = 0.57104
x = 20.9 value = 0.54572        x = 21 value = 0.5              x = 21.1 value = 0.450428       x = 21.2 value = 0.405792
x = 21.3 value = 0.374462       x = 21.4 value = 0.363488       x = 21.5 value = 0.375          x = 21.6 value = 0.404768
x = 21.7 value = 0.442922       x = 21.8 value = 0.476832       x = 21.9 value = 0.496148       x = 22 value = 0.5
x = 22.1 value = 0.5            x = 22.2 value = 0.5            x = 22.3 value = 0.5            x = 22.4 value = 0.5
x = 22.5 value = 0.5            x = 22.6 value = 0.5            x = 22.7 value = 0.5            x = 22.8 value = 0.5
x = 22.9 value = 0.5            x = 23 value = 0.5              x = 23.1 value = 0.503852       x = 23.2 value = 0.523168
x = 23.3 value = 0.557078       x = 23.4 value = 0.595232       x = 23.5 value = 0.625          x = 23.6 value = 0.636512
x = 23.7 value = 0.625538       x = 23.8 value = 0.594208       x = 23.9 value = 0.549572       x = 24 value = 0.5
x = 24.1 value = 0.45428        x = 24.2 value = 0.42896        x = 24.3 value = 0.43154        x = 24.4 value = 0.45872
x = 24.5 value = 0.5            x = 24.6 value = 0.54128        x = 24.7 value = 0.56846        x = 24.8 value = 0.57104
x = 24.9 value = 0.54572        x = 25 value = 0.5              x = 25.1 value = 0.450428       x = 25.2 value = 0.405792
x = 25.3 value = 0.374462       x = 25.4 value = 0.363488       x = 25.5 value = 0.375          x = 25.6 value = 0.404768
x = 25.7 value = 0.442922       x = 25.8 value = 0.476832       x = 25.9 value = 0.496148       x = 26 value = 0.5
x = 26.1 value = 0.5            x = 26.2 value = 0.5            x = 26.3 value = 0.5            x = 26.4 value = 0.5
x = 26.5 value = 0.5            x = 26.6 value = 0.5            x = 26.7 value = 0.5            x = 26.8 value = 0.5
x = 26.9 value = 0.5            x = 27 value = 0.5              x = 27.1 value = 0.503852       x = 27.2 value = 0.523168
x = 27.3 value = 0.557078       x = 27.4 value = 0.595232       x = 27.5 value = 0.625          x = 27.6 value = 0.636512
x = 27.7 value = 0.625538       x = 27.8 value = 0.594208       x = 27.9 value = 0.549572       x = 28 value = 0.5
x = 28.1 value = 0.450428       x = 28.2 value = 0.405792       x = 28.3 value = 0.374462       x = 28.4 value = 0.363488
x = 28.5 value = 0.375          x = 28.6 value = 0.404768       x = 28.7 value = 0.442922       x = 28.8 value = 0.476832
x = 28.9 value = 0.496148       x = 29 value = 0.5              x = 29.1 value = 0.503852       x = 29.2 value = 0.523168
x = 29.3 value = 0.557078       x = 29.4 value = 0.595232       x = 29.5 value = 0.625          x = 29.6 value = 0.636512
x = 29.7 value = 0.625538       x = 29.8 value = 0.594208       x = 29.9 value = 0.549572       x = 30 value = 0.5
x = 30.1 value = 0.446576       x = 30.2 value = 0.382623       x = 30.3 value = 0.317383       x = 30.4 value = 0.268256
x = 30.5 value = 0.25           x = 30.6 value = 0.268256       x = 30.7 value = 0.317384       x = 30.8 value = 0.382625
x = 30.9 value = 0.446576       x = 31 value = 0.5              x = 31.1 value = 0.54572        x = 31.2 value = 0.57104
x = 31.3 value = 0.56846        x = 31.4 value = 0.54128        x = 31.5 value = 0.5            x = 31.6 value = 0.45872
x = 31.7 value = 0.43154        x = 31.8 value = 0.42896        x = 31.9 value = 0.45428        x = 32 value = 0.5
x = 32.1 value = 0.545721       x = 32.2 value = 0.57104        x = 32.3 value = 0.56846        x = 32.4 value = 0.541279
x = 32.5 value = 0.5            x = 32.6 value = 0.458719       x = 32.7 value = 0.43154        x = 32.8 value = 0.42896
x = 32.9 value = 0.45428        x = 33 value = 0.5              x = 33.1 value = 0.545721       x = 33.2 value = 0.57104
x = 33.3 value = 0.56846        x = 33.4 value = 0.541279       x = 33.5 value = 0.5            x = 33.6 value = 0.458719
x = 33.7 value = 0.43154        x = 33.8 value = 0.42896        x = 33.9 value = 0.45428        x = 34 value = 0.5
x = 34.1 value = 0.545721       x = 34.2 value = 0.57104        x = 34.3 value = 0.56846        x = 34.4 value = 0.541279
x = 34.5 value = 0.5            x = 34.6 value = 0.458719       x = 34.7 value = 0.43154        x = 34.8 value = 0.42896
x = 34.9 value = 0.45428        x = 35 value = 0.5              x = 35.1 value = 0.553425       x = 35.2 value = 0.617377
x = 35.3 value = 0.682616       x = 35.4 value = 0.731745       x = 35.5 value = 0.75           x = 35.6 value = 0.731743
x = 35.7 value = 0.682616       x = 35.8 value = 0.617377       x = 35.9 value = 0.553423       x = 36 value = 0.5
x = 36.1 value = 0.450427       x = 36.2 value = 0.405792       x = 36.3 value = 0.374462       x = 36.4 value = 0.363488
x = 36.5 value = 0.375          x = 36.6 value = 0.404769       x = 36.7 value = 0.442922       x = 36.8 value = 0.476832
x = 36.9 value = 0.496148       x = 37 value = 0.5              x = 37.1 value = 0.503852       x = 37.2 value = 0.523168
x = 37.3 value = 0.557078       x = 37.4 value = 0.595233       x = 37.5 value = 0.625          x = 37.6 value = 0.636512
x = 37.7 value = 0.625538       x = 37.8 value = 0.594208       x = 37.9 value = 0.549571       x = 38 value = 0.5
x = 38.1 value = 0.446575       x = 38.2 value = 0.382623       x = 38.3 value = 0.317384       x = 38.4 value = 0.268255
x = 38.5 value = 0.25           x = 38.6 value = 0.268257       x = 38.7 value = 0.317384       x = 38.8 value = 0.382623
x = 38.9 value = 0.446577       x = 39 value = 0.5              x = 39.1 value = 0.545721       x = 39.2 value = 0.57104
x = 39.3 value = 0.56846        x = 39.4 value = 0.541279       x = 39.5 value = 0.5            x = 39.6 value = 0.458719
x = 39.7 value = 0.43154        x = 39.8 value = 0.42896        x = 39.9 value = 0.45428        x = 40 value = 0.5
x = 40.1 value = 0.545721       x = 40.2 value = 0.57104        x = 40.3 value = 0.56846        x = 40.4 value = 0.541279
x = 40.5 value = 0.5            x = 40.6 value = 0.458719       x = 40.7 value = 0.43154        x = 40.8 value = 0.42896
x = 40.9 value = 0.45428        x = 41 value = 0.5              x = 41.1 value = 0.549573       x = 41.2 value = 0.594208
x = 41.3 value = 0.625538       x = 41.4 value = 0.636512       x = 41.5 value = 0.625          x = 41.6 value = 0.595231
x = 41.7 value = 0.557078       x = 41.8 value = 0.523168       x = 41.9 value = 0.503852       x = 42 value = 0.5
x = 42.1 value = 0.496148       x = 42.2 value = 0.476832       x = 42.3 value = 0.442922       x = 42.4 value = 0.404767
x = 42.5 value = 0.375          x = 42.6 value = 0.363488       x = 42.7 value = 0.374462       x = 42.8 value = 0.405792
x = 42.9 value = 0.450429       x = 43 value = 0.5              x = 43.1 value = 0.545721       x = 43.2 value = 0.57104
x = 43.3 value = 0.56846        x = 43.4 value = 0.541279       x = 43.5 value = 0.5            x = 43.6 value = 0.458719
x = 43.7 value = 0.43154        x = 43.8 value = 0.42896        x = 43.9 value = 0.45428        x = 44 value = 0.5
x = 44.1 value = 0.553425       x = 44.2 value = 0.617377       x = 44.3 value = 0.682616       x = 44.4 value = 0.731745
x = 44.5 value = 0.75           x = 44.6 value = 0.731743       x = 44.7 value = 0.682616       x = 44.8 value = 0.617377
x = 44.9 value = 0.553423       x = 45 value = 0.5              x = 45.1 value = 0.454279       x = 45.2 value = 0.42896
x = 45.3 value = 0.43154        x = 45.4 value = 0.458721       x = 45.5 value = 0.5            x = 45.6 value = 0.541281
x = 45.7 value = 0.56846        x = 45.8 value = 0.57104        x = 45.9 value = 0.54572        x = 46 value = 0.5
x = 46.1 value = 0.454279       x = 46.2 value = 0.42896        x = 46.3 value = 0.43154        x = 46.4 value = 0.458721
x = 46.5 value = 0.5            x = 46.6 value = 0.541281       x = 46.7 value = 0.56846        x = 46.8 value = 0.57104
x = 46.9 value = 0.54572        x = 47 value = 0.5              x = 47.1 value = 0.450427       x = 47.2 value = 0.405792
x = 47.3 value = 0.374462       x = 47.4 value = 0.363488       x = 47.5 value = 0.375          x = 47.6 value = 0.404769
x = 47.7 value = 0.442922       x = 47.8 value = 0.476832       x = 47.9 value = 0.496148       x = 48 value = 0.5
x = 48.1 value = 0.5            x = 48.2 value = 0.5            x = 48.3 value = 0.5            x = 48.4 value = 0.5
x = 48.5 value = 0.5            x = 48.6 value = 0.5            x = 48.7 value = 0.5            x = 48.8 value = 0.5
x = 48.9 value = 0.5            x = 49 value = 0.5              x = 49.1 value = 0.5            x = 49.2 value = 0.5
x = 49.3 value = 0.5            x = 49.4 value = 0.5            x = 49.5 value = 0.5            x = 49.6 value = 0.5
x = 49.7 value = 0.5            x = 49.8 value = 0.5            x = 49.9 value = 0.5            x = 50 value = 0.5
x = 50.1 value = 0.496148       x = 50.2 value = 0.476832       x = 50.3 value = 0.442922       x = 50.4 value = 0.404767
x = 50.5 value = 0.375          x = 50.6 value = 0.363488       x = 50.7 value = 0.374462       x = 50.8 value = 0.405792
x = 50.9 value = 0.450429       x = 51 value = 0.5              x = 51.1 value = 0.545721       x = 51.2 value = 0.57104
x = 51.3 value = 0.56846        x = 51.4 value = 0.541279       x = 51.5 value = 0.5            x = 51.6 value = 0.458719
x = 51.7 value = 0.43154        x = 51.8 value = 0.42896        x = 51.9 value = 0.45428        x = 52 value = 0.5
```

As you can see there are blocks of 0.5 values. How can I change the code, so that these 0.5 values turn into correct perlin noise value?

Comment: I only iterated over the first (x) dimension...

Comment: What is the value of `repeat`? (the .h file seems missing).

Comment: Repeat has the value -1